# Variable font height according to Org header

Tags: org-mode, fonts

This seems like it's probably not possible, but I'm extremely new to Emacs and thought I'd ask.

I have a number of faces set in Org mode.

```
;; Highlight Line Colors
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
(set-face-attribute 'org-level-1 nil                   :family "Mordens" :font "Mordens" :height 520 :foreground "#FDF0ED")
(set-face-attribute 'org-level-2 nil                   :family "Iosevka Nerd Font" :font "Iosevka Nerd Font" :height 220 :foreground "#25B2BC")
(set-face-attribute 'org-level-3 nil                   :family "Iosevka Nerd Font" :font "Iosevka Nerd Font" :height 160)
(set-face-attribute 'org-level-4 nil                   :family "Iosevka Nerd Font" :font "Iosevka Nerd Font" :height 160 :italic nil)
(set-face-attribute 'org-document-title nil            :family "Iosevka Nerd Font" :font "Iosevka Nerd Font" :height 160 :italic 1 :foreground "#2E303E")
(set-face-attribute 'org-document-info nil             :family "Iosevka Nerd Font" :font "Iosevka Nerd Font" :height 160 :italic 1 :foreground "#2E303E")
(set-face-attribute 'org-document-info-keyword nil     :family "Iosevka Nerd Font" :font "Iosevka Nerd Font" :height 160 :italic 1 :foreground "#2E303E")
(set-face-attribute 'org-headline-done nil             :family "Iosevka Nerd Font" :font "Iosevka Nerd Font" :height 160 :italic 1 :foreground "#6C6F93" :strike-through "#F43E5C" )
(set-face-attribute 'org-done nil                      :family "Iosevka Nerd Font" :font "Iosevka Nerd Font" :height 160 :italic 1 :foreground "#6C6F93" :strike-through nil )
(set-face-attribute 'org-todo nil                      :family "Iosevka Nerd Font" :font "Iosevka Nerd Font" :height 160 :italic 1 :foreground "#E95379")
(set-face-attribute 'org-checkbox-statistics-todo nil  :family "Iosevka Nerd Font" :font "Iosevka Nerd Font" :height 160 :foreground "#09F7A0")
(set-face-attribute '+org-todo-project nil             :family "Iosevka Nerd Font" :font "Iosevka Nerd Font" :height 1.0 :foreground "#B877DB")
(set-face-attribute 'org-link nil                      :family "Iosevka Nerd Font" :font "Iosevka Nerd Font" :height 160 :italic 1 :underline "#FDF0ED" :foreground "#09F7A0")
(set-face-attribute 'line-number-current-line nil      :foreground "#09F7A0")))
```

What I would like to do is set `+org-todo-project`'s height to the height of the header where it occurs.

Note: `+org-todo-project` sets the face for the keyword `PROJ`.

For example:

```
* PROJ This is a Project ;Header 1 Height 520
** PROJ This is another Project ; Header 2 Height 220
```

I've tried to search around, but again Emacs is a big placem so if it's possible I don't know what I am looking for. I thought trying a `dolist` to see if it would inherit the height but I'm pretty sure it would just inherit the last height before it, if at all.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TODO` keywords in a heading use both the `org-todo` and `org-level-` faces. Does it work as expected if you don't set the `:height` attribute of the `org-todo` face?

If you are looking to customize how the `TODO` keywords are displayed, you might want to check [org-superstar-mode](https://github.com/integral-dw/org-superstar-mode) (in particular the documentation for `org-superstar-todo-bullet-alist`)

Comment: Sure does. Thanks! Is there a way to see what is inherited from something else?

Comment: Also after I remove the customization and restart it's set again. Is there a way like in vim to see the last place a property/variable is set?

Comment: try `M-x describe-face` with a selected region or the name of a face. you should see `(customize this face)` which you can click to get into an editing interface, any saved changes should appear in `~/.emacs.d/custom.el`

Comment: This is helpful. I'm using Doom Emacs and never thought of looking outside the .doom.d directory. Also just in case anyone else stumbles on this you can set any font property to `unspecified, which also resolved the issue.